# Changing HTML with Javascript when a link is clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a DIV named "videoplayer" -- inside this DIV is an image.

Is there a simple way to change the HTML code inside this DIV when a link is clicked on?

For example, this is the current DIV:

```
    <div class = "big_player" id="player1">
             <img src="whatever.jpg">
    </div>
```

When a link is clicked, I want the HTML to change to:

```
    <div class = "big_player" id="player1">
             <script>
                playVideo(file, stream, key);
             </script>
    </div>
```

**I have multiple thumbnails/links (12 in total) with all different 'file, stream, key' variables.** Please take a look [here](http://spuxystudios.com/mvibo/30day_new2/) for reference.

What is the simplest and easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: It can be done easily with jQuery, but where do file, stream, key come from?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; read the [faq]. When your existing question isn't getting enough traffic, the correct solution is to edit it to be a better question. It's ***not*** acceptable to simply repost the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's pretty simple.

```
var div = document.getElementById("player1");
div.onmousedown = function() {
    div.innerHTML = "stuff!"
};
```

JSFiddle: (click on test) http://jsfiddle.net/yjdfg/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function like this:

```
function changeDiv(divID) {
    var div_to_change = document.getElementById(divID);
    div_to_change.innerHTML = 'whatever you want here';
}
```

and call with

```
<a onClick="changeDiv('player1')" href="#">Click to change div</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to run the script on click:

```
$('#player1').click(function(){playVideo(file, stream, key);});
```

That would work for one of them (player1), you need to do it for the rest. Note that you must define your function parameters also (file, stream, key) or grab them from the div attributes, for example.
If they are dynamic, use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `click`.

However, if you really want to change the contents of the div (for whatever the reason), this is the code to put inside the click function:

```
var html_code = "<script>playVideo(file, stream, key);</script>";
$('#player1').html(html_code);
```

EDIT

After visiting your site, I've noticed that you're not clicking the big div to change its contents, but the other ones. In that case, the proper selectors are `#miniplayer1`, `#miniplayer2`, etc. so that the original code becomes `$('#miniplayer1').click(function(){playVideo(file, stream, key);});`